# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, dataframe, databricks

I have a dataframe and I want to make a deep copy of it so I can modify the copy and use it in further processing. 
I am working in Azure Databricks.

My dataframe is called "a" and I tried the following command:

```
b = a.copy(deep=True)
```

When I run it, I encounter the following error :

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I also tried to use 'iloc' or 'loc' function to create a new dataframe only with the columns that I need, but same error ('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'lit').

Any ideas why is this happening?..

Comment: What does `print(type(a))` output?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're working in Python, check whether you're using a ***Spark DataFrame*** or a ***pandas DataFrame***. If you're using a ***pandas*** one then I couldn't tell you what's going on without more information; if you're using the ***spark*** one then you should use

```
newDataFrame = oldDataFrame.select('*')
```

Comment: Excellent concise answer that can potentially save some headaches.

Comment: I also faced same issue and as I was working on data bricks with cluster I followed your suggestion and use this step but now I am facing issue in subsequent steps ~~~monthly_Imp_data_import_anaplan.fillna(0, inplace=True)~~~----error inplace, similarly for ~~~anaplan_upload_file = monthly_Imp_data_import_anaplan.astype('string')~~~-- as type is error so what I feel it is becuase of pysparl dataframe but what should be the solution

Comment: @Ashish I couldn't even guess what's going on without seeing the errors messages. maybe if you post your own question it will be more clear?